# SQL Server 2008 R2: Count character match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The following is the given pattern to count the occurrences.

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(20) = ' ??? ? ?? '
```

Want to count the occurrences of `?`.

**Expected Count**: 6

**My try**:  1

```
SET @Pattern = LEN(@Pattern) - LEN(REPLACE(@Pattern,'?',''));

PRINT(@Pattern)
```

Result: 9

**My try**:  2

```
SET @Pattern = LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@SDPattern)));

PRINT(@Pattern)
```

Result: 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is almost right. `LEN` does not count trailing spaces. So in this case you should use `datalength`

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(20) = ' ??? ? ?? '
SET @Pattern = DATALENGTH(@Pattern) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@Pattern,'?',''));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `len()` function ignores trailing spaces. In order to measure the actual length of the string, you need to use the `datalength()` function.

However, be aware that it counts bytes rather than characters. So, for example, this will give you double of what you might expect:

```
declare @v nvarchar(20) = N'we?i?gf 349?08 d ? ';

select datalength(@v) - datalength(replace(@v, N'?', N''));
```